# How to know if user is authenticated on the first request with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Given a backend wrote in nodejs that returns a page that should either link to login (if the user is not logged in) or a link to logout (if the users is already logged in).

Considering I'm using firebase as authentication tool, how can I know in the first request, when the user is accessing the website, if is he authenticated to then 
 set the ejs template to respond with the correct link ?

Is there some header, or token that can I use ?

The only solution I found was use ajax after the server response, but I don't like this solution because apparently there is a delay in the link renderization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to know if the user is authentication on the initial request. From a quick inspection no data is sent along with that request. That kinda makes sense, given that upon this request it is not even known if you're using authentication to being with.

### Update

I actually just ran into this blog post from one of the Firebase engineers, which seems promising: [Introducing session cookies for server-side web apps](https://medium.com/@hiranya911/firebase-introducing-session-cookies-for-server-side-web-apps-fb46cce40b2). I haven't fully read it yet, but the title sounds like it may be exactly what you want.